# What does "Giving an overall running time" mean in this context?

Tags: algorithm

In the following image
[click me for an image because I need 10 rep first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j57Eh.png)

The author refers to an overall running time linear to |E|. But the author then says this is at most O(n^2). This seems contradictory because O(n^2) is quadratic time. Did the author mean to write something else? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: This question is kinda off-topic for stackoverflow. I'd recommend moving the question over to [CS StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your link. I think you are right.  I will move my question there instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been moved to another site in the Stack Exchange network.